# NSMutableAttributedString: How to delete last character programmatically on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, string, nsmutableattributedstring

I have a custom keyboard and I have to perform backspace action on textview having nsmutableattributed string as a text (combination of character and nstextattachments)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per Moxy: if your last character is large enough not to fit within a single UTF-16 unit then Dave's method will just truncate the description of that character. Emojis are an example [but there are a bunch more](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/stringsClusters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008025).

So you'll more likely want:

```
[string deleteCharactersInRange:
    [string.string rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:string.length - 1]]
```

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 4**

```
mutableAttributedString.deleteCharacters(in: NSRange(location:(mutableAttributedString.length) - 1,length:1))
```